# loop macro for dates to run a SAS query

Tags: sas, teradata, sas-macro, proc-sql, do-loops

I have a requirement to pull millions of data for more than 10,000 Ids at an event level for the last few years. I tried to use `SAS macro` to pull the data for each month however the query fails due to some threshold limits on the tables

```
 Data looks like this

 ID     Date      amount     seq
 101   1/15/2015   $100       a101
 101   1/17/2017   $100       b101
 101   3/15/2018   $50        c101
 101   3/21/2018   $200       d101

.......................
.......................
20001  2/15/2022   $100      a20001 
20001  3/18/2022   $10       b20001

My query

%macro  data(no,Start,End);
proc sql;
create table AllDataPoints as 
select * from connection to Teradata
(
 select dsitinct Id, seq, date, amount
 from table
 where date between &start and &end
);
quit;
%mend;

%data(1,'2015-01-01','2015-01-31');
%data(2,'2015-02-01','2015-02-28');
 ...
 ...
%data(12,'2015-12-01','2015-12-31');
```

I would repeat this for years 2015 thru 2022 but query fails due to some table limitations.
Is there a way I can write a `loop macro` to repeat this for each day and later append all the data?

Thanks

Comment: Have you copied the code in correctly? As it stands 'dsitinct' is spelt wrong so the query on teradata won't run. Once that is corrected then you'll find the query just keeps extracting to the same table `AllDataPoints` - the macro variable `&no` is not used

Comment: It was my bad.. &no - I would be creating my datasets using this macro variable e.g. AllDataPoints_1, AllDataPoints_2 etc.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the data once in SAS?  You can likely do some aggregate computations more effectively remotely and download the results to SAS.

Comment: What do you mean by `some table limitations`? Are you getting an error?  Addressing that might be a better option than trying to implement some sort of loop.

Comment: It gives me "Teradata row not delivered" error

Comment: @ckp - there should be more to that, you should be seeing the actual Teradata error. Assuming that there is one, I guess, but I suspect there is.

Comment: How are you going to process those records in SAS? In most cases it's possible to do (at least part of) it in Teradata, there are lots of built-in Analytic Functions for statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to do it by day, you can modify your macro as follows:

```
%macro data(Start, End, out);

    /* Convert to SAS date */
    %let start_date = %sysfunc(inputn(&start, yymmdd10.));
    %let end_date   = %sysfunc(inputn(&end, yymmdd10.));

    /* Delete previous table */
    proc delete data=&out;
    run;

    /* Loop through every day */
    %do i = &start_date %to &end_date;

        /* Convert to yyyy-mm-dd for Teradata */
        %let date  = %sysfunc(putn(&i, yymmddd10.) );

        proc sql;
            create table _tmp_data_ as 
            select * from connection to Teradata
            (
             select distinct Id, seq, date, amount
             from table
             where date = %tslit(&date)
            );
        quit;

        /* Append to a master dataset */
        proc append base=&out. data=_tmp_data_ force;
        run;

    %end;
%mend;

%data(2015-01-01, 2015-12-31, AllDataPoints);
```

The only change you need to make is to not use quotes when specifying your start/end dates, and specify a final output dataset.

Comment: Thanks Stu.. The code is not creating any dataset and the log file also doesn't show any errors

Comment: Does the date need to be in single quotes?

Comment: yes.. teradata expects the date to be in quotes
e.g. date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31'

Comment: @ckp try using the updated code.